# kivy pydrive buildozer ImportError: No module named iri2uri

Tags: python, kivy, pydrive

I have a kivy app, which runs on my linux desktop.

I can also build it with buildozer and run the app on my android phone.

I include a sync with google-drive through the pydrive modul -> works on linux.

I added PyDrive to the requirements in my buildozer.spec file but when i run my app on android ,I get the following error on my phone via adb:

```
I/python  (16976):    File "/home/taper/Dokumente/py-spielwiese/myapp/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 23, in <module>
I/python  (16976):    File "/home/taper/Dokumente/py-spielwiese/myapp/.buildozer/android/app/drivesync.py", line 1, in  <module>
I/python  (16976):    File "/home/taper/Dokumente/py-spielwiese/myapp/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs/pydrive/drive.py", line 2, in <module>
I/python  (16976):    File "/home/taper/Dokumente/py-spielwiese/myapp/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs/pydrive/files.py", line 4, in <module>
I/python  (16976):    File "/home/taper/Dokumente/py-spielwiese/myapp/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs/apiclient/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
I/python  (16976):    File "/home/taper/Dokumente/py-spielwiese/myapp/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 50, in <module>
I/python  (16976):    File "/home/taper/Dokumente/py-spielwiese/myapp/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs/httplib2/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
I/python  (16976):  ImportError: No module named iri2uri
```

Answer (score 0):

Some modules are blacklisted. You can check in .buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/src/blacklist.txt if iri2uri is.
Also you can try to add iri2uri to you buildozer.spec requirements

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar problem. I'm trying to send an email using the GMail API with OAuth2 authentication. It works on my PC, but it crashes immediately on my smartphone.

I tried to include iri2uri in the buildozer.spec, but buildozer couldn't create the APK.

I'm not sure if it helps, but in this thread someone suggest to use an Android flow instead of a web flow.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!starred/kivy-users/3K9y1X0QcHM